# Не отображается элемент меню

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Пытаюсь поместить элемент меню на панель действий. Для этого создал такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

В активности устанавливаю меню так (унаследован от класса `Activity`):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

В приложении используется тема `android:Theme.Material.Light`.

---

В результате отображается только название приложения и дополнительная область с действиями (три точечки) в которой и находится элемент действия. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Т.е. пункта этого `action_create_order` нет?..

Comment: app:showAsAction="never" из-за этого скорей всего

Comment: Может вместо `app:showAsAction` надо `android:showAsAction` писать, раз активити не из либы поддержки?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, пункт находится в раскрывающемся списке действий. При попытке написать `android:showAsAction` выдает ошибку `Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, этот параметр применет к другому айтему.

Comment: А это у вас на девайсе или в превью?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, активность не из библиотеки поддержки, но зависимость от нее в проекте. К сожалению, на девайсе. Как это просмотреть в превью я, по правде говоря, не понял...

Comment: А тулбар встроенный или из разметки?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как их различать? Я ничего, вроде, с тулбаром не делал :).

Comment: Думаю, дело в теме... Попробуйте таки из библиотеки поддержки тему использовать. или попробуйте вместо этого прописать так: `app:showAsAction="always|ifRoom"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, `app:showAsAction="always|ifRoom"` не помогло. А тема должна так работать. В учебнике написано же, что должно. Правда там написано и то, что может не работать из-за бага в библиотеке...........

Comment: Других идей кроме как использовать таки либу поддержки у меня нет(

Comment: Может пункт меню не влазит, название приложение много место занимает. В вертикальном положении девайса тоже не показывает пункт меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По книжке действительно не получается. Нужно писать android:showAsAction="ifRoom" и android:showAsAction="never". Android Studio поругается, что Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", но приложение скомпилируется и запустится как положено (если убрать зависимость от библиотек поддержки, предупреждений не будет).

Comment: Как бы Вы немного опоздали.... :))